# How do I read another bot's embed's author field?

Tags: discord, discord.js

**Edit:**

I figured it out, you could find another bot's embeds's author field

```js
message.embeds[0].author.name
```

---

**Original question:**

[To be clear about 'author', this is the 'author' I'm mentioning.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iglmB.jpg)

I already wrote a regex to detect if an embed's author include [username] searched the [place]:

```js
const matches = message.embeds[0].author.match(new RegExp("\\*\\*<@!?\\d{1,}> searched the:\\*\\*"));
```

but there's an error:

`TypeError: cannot read property 'author' of undefined`

Would appreciate some help, thank you!

Comment: It means `message.embeds[0]` is undefined. How do you get `message`? Can you update your question with that part?

Comment: I'm fetching via message events

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, undefined has no property author. This means embeds[0] is undefined. It is quite likely the message sent has no embeds, so you should probably put that line inside `if(typeof message.embeds[0] !== 'undefined') {` to stop the code running if there is no embed.